# Compound select query in Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, select, oracle10g

I have a table, `mealdb`, which has three fields viz. `"userid", "timeofday", "daydate"`(all `varchar2`). `timeofday` can have two values, "noon" or "afternoon". Now I want to calculate the total number of afternoons against a given userid. I tried like

```
select sum(timeofday) 
  from mealdb 
 where timeofday='afternoon' where userid='1200';
```

But it is giving an error in Oracle 10g.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Change `sum(timeofday)` to `count(1)` and `where timeofday='afternoon' where userid='1200';
` to `where timeofday='afternoon' and userid='1200'. I suggest you go through basic SQL tutorial as filtering data is one of the basic parts of writing SQL.
`

Comment: Thank you.I learned SQL a long time ago and has not been in touch for a good time.Thanks fir the advice.

Comment: Sorry to inform...But the code you suggested did not work.It shows [code]select count(timeofday) from mealdb where  userid='mistu4u';[code] as 4 like already entered in my table.But when I add clause [code]where timeofday='afternoon'[code] it shows 0.Please have a look!!

Comment: By the way the problem has been resolved by using  select count(timeofday) from mealdb
WHERE timeofday='Noon' and userid='mistu4u';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(1) 
  from mealdb 
 where timeofday='afternoon' and userid='1200';
```

Comment: Sorry to inform...But the code you suggested did not work.It shows ['code'] select count(timeofday) from mealdb where  userid='mistu4u';['code'] as 4 like already entered in my table.But when I add clause ['code'] where timeofday='afternoon'['code']  it shows 0.Please have a look!!

Comment: Can you specify what's the content of mealdb table? Query *should* work if you're trying to retrieve the data specified in your question.

Comment: Like I already described in my question,all the contents are in the mealdb table.Thanks anyway for your help!!

Comment: By the way the problem has been resolved by using select count(timeofday) from mealdb WHERE timeofday='Noon' and userid='mistu4u';

Answer (score 2):

Only one `WHERE` keyword is allowed.

Further conditions are added using boolean operators like `AND`, `OR`

```
select count(*) 
from mealdb 
where timeofday='afternoon' 
  and userid='1200';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `select count(timeofday) from mealdb where timeofday='afternoon' and userid='1200'` You need to use `Count` not `Sum` and use `and` where your second `where` is.